# js how to press button without id?

Tags: javascript, button, click

How to press at this button on js?

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-lg">Confirm</button>
```

i tryed this `document.getElementsByClassName('btn-lg').Click();` but it not working.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('btn-lg')[0] - if first element with that class is in question....

Answer (score 1):

document.querySelector(".btn-lg").onclick = function() { alert("clicked") }

Comment: This works (and I'm not suggesting this is a bad answer, by the way, given the scope of the question), but it points at the flaw in the original markup. The querySelector() function returns a reference to "the first element that is a descendant of the element on which it is invoked that matches the specified group of selectors." If another element with the class "btn-lg" ever comes before the confirmation button, the handler will apply to that element, instead. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ajnq7h0q/1/

Comment: By the way, I think the original poster actually wants to click the button, so you'd actually want document.querySelector(".btn-lg").click(). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ajnq7h0q/3/

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName returns html collection (array-like object) of the objects which have a specified class. So you should filter unneeded elements by going through the collection (in the same way as you go through an array)

Comment: Maybe i can do it with document.getElementsByTagName?

Comment: @user3613542 it also returns html collection... but the collection of buttons (if you user 'button' as a param to that function). You have to identify this button. For instance, it may be the only button with the text "confirm" or it may be the only button within form, etc... in this case you make sure you're going to click the button you want to click